# Simplest algorithm to cover a sphere

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

What is the simplest algorithm for covering the surface of a sphere by walking. To word it another way, what would be the simplest algorithm a person could take to walk the surface of the earth?

Comment: What kind of covering do you want? Do we have to visit _every_ point?

Comment: How big are your footprints?

Comment: Are you looking for a [space filling curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve)?

Comment: Please see the comments following my answer.  Have I misinterpreted the intent behind your query?

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, I'm looking for a space-filling curve - something which will approach full coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Start at the South Pole, and walk north along the line of longitude that represents Greenwich Mean Time.  Travel along this line of longitude via the following algorithm:

Take 1 step north.

Then make a complete circle along the corresponding line of latitude until you return to the pertinent line of longitude.

Then, rinse and repeat until you reach the North Pole.

Comment: Did you really mean "rinse"?

Comment: Yes, I do not know if you are a native speaker of English or not, but the expression "rinse & repeat" means to do a task over and over again, whether it requires rinsing or not. @RobArthan https://www.google.com/search?q=rinse+and+repeat+meaning&rlz=1C1GCEB_enUS916US916&oq=rinse+and+r&aqs=chrome.3.0i433j0j69i57j0l5.3323j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Since you are only taking steps of $1$, how would you reach the rational numbers and irrationals?

Comment: I am a native speaker of English and I have never heard that expression before. I suggest you keep it for home consumption, wherever you learnt your English. To go back to the mathematics, I don't think you can come up with a space-filling curve that is as simple as the one you propose.

Comment: @SomeGuy I'm not sure that I understand your question.  It is understood that you would be covering the surface of the earth, along each line of latitude, by a width equal to the width of your shoe(s).  So, to avoid skipping any portion of the earth's surface, you would limit the size of the steps along the line of longitude to the width of your shoe(s).  If this type of presumption is disallowed, then I am at a loss at how any algorithm might be designed to cover *every infintesimally small portion of the earth's surface*.  ...see next comment

Comment: @SomeGuy Consequently, since I can't even envision how any algorithm could be applied to infintesimally small portions of the earth's surface, I interpreted the original query as allowing my original algorithm to be construed as appropriate.

Comment: @RobArthan See my previous two comments.

Comment: @RobArthan "I suggest you keep it for home consumption, wherever you learnt your English." That's pretty rude. Even if the expression were incomprehensible (and it's not; it's a very common saying), there's no reason to get so snarky about it.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude. I was just seriously suggesting that using that idiom here is not adding any value.